# Jquery UI Progress Bar with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have tried to implement the Jquery UI Progress Bar without success by following this tutorial here http://t.wits.sg/2008/06/25/howto-php-and-jquery-upload-progress-bar/

APC is installed and working on the server so the issue must be the code below, but I'm at a dead end and just cant work out why it wont update the progress bar. I think I've changed the code correctly to work with the Jquery UI progress bar rather than the one they are referencing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the value of "data" in "showUpload()" ?

Comment: What would be the best way of finding that out? (sorry for such a simple question)

Comment: No need to apologize, that's what this place is for.  :-)  alert(print_r(data));   http://scriptnode.com/article/javascript-print_r-or-var_dump-equivalent/

Comment: I put that code straight after $.get("test.php?id=" + progress_key, function(data) { and nothing came up so I'm guessing null :o(

Comment: it's probably not executing that line. Try moving it up before the return statement.

Comment: I tried the following but nothing appeared :(

function showUpload() {
 $.get("test.php?id=" + progress_key, function(data) {
  alert(print_r(data));
  if (!data)
   return;

Comment: try just alert('hi'); move up the function calls line by line. See if you can get it to fire. Chances are showUpload() isn't be called. Try to use firebug if you can.

Comment: You're right! The function "beginUpload" isn't even being called. So I guess it needs to be called somehow when the form is submitted?

Comment: You can add it as a callback to the fadeOut, or you can just invoke it plainly.

Comment: If you're out of the woods, want to mark my answer as the solution? Or do you need some more help?

Comment: It still doesn't work but I think I might be able to use your advice and debug line by line. Thanks for that, it's been a good learning experience.

Comment: No problem. Take the time to learn firebug (and google chrome inspector). I use both heavily everyday. Client-side development without it is insanity. Happy debugging!

Comment: David, how are you invoking beginUpload() ?

Comment: I'm doing this: <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form" id="form" onsubmit="beginUpload()">

Comment: ahh... didn't see it in the code... good luck with your troubleshooting...

Comment: cheers! It's not going very well lol

Comment: Can you join this chat?  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/747/specificjavascriptquestion?tab=general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test your assumptions. Put a debug statement into your code to test to see what the values are.

```
alert(print_r(data));
```

http://scriptnode.com/article/javascript-print_r-or-var_dump-equivalent/

Also, you can use firebug's breakpoints to stop the code from executing on a certain line. Once the code has halted, you can inspect the values of each variable in the stack.

http://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html