# What is the best way to create a progress bar for data processing?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

This is is my case:

I upload an Excel file and each row is read into a table. Then each row in the table is processed before the user gets feedback. This processing can take some time.

How can I create a progress bar that shows how many % of the rows has been processed?

My solution is using MySQL, PHP and jQuery.

**UPDATE**
It seems people don't understand my question.

I'm not asking how I can implement [jQuery progress bar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/#animated), that is the easy part.
I'm asking what logic do I need to implement in PHP to send data back after each insertion.

After I click `Submit` on my form, data + file is sent for processing. For each row inserted, I somehow want to update the progress bar.

Since the form data is submitted to it's own page, I don't see how I can use jQuery progressbar - even though I want to use it.

How do I send data back while the processing continues? Do I use some sort of `CRON`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this would work for your current solution, and I don't think I will provide any sample code because I can't see your code. But I will at least type up my idea.

Since you are using MySQL you could create a table to hold the progress data of your processing.
For example you could store a 'session ID', a 'total count of the rows in the file' and the 'last row which was processed'.

While you are processing your file's rows you can `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` the progress table (The 'session ID' being your key).

Of course if you have a large file this could be making more queries in your database than you really want, so you could for example update the table every 10 rows and then finally update when the last row is processed to lower the number of calls to your database.

While all of this is happening your user will be waiting on a page with your jQuery UI progress bar.

This page can make timed AJAX calls to a PHP file which would query your progress table to get the 'last row number processed' and the 'total row count'.

Once you have this information returned via your AJAX call you can use the AJAX success function to do some simple maths with the 'last row updated' and 'total rows' number to update your jQuery progress bar.

When the progress bar is updated to 100% the AJAX could make one last call to delete the row from your progress table.

It isn't perfect but it is an idea at least.

I'm sorry I can't provide any sample code but I feel it would be a waste of time without seeing your current implementation and without knowing if this is the kind of solution you are looking for.

Comment: That was actually not a bad idea. I can submit the data using AJAX, then run a loop in jQuery fetching progress data from table and update the progress bar. Once it reached 100%, I can continue the work and close the progress bar.

Comment: PS. What can you see as the downside using this method?

Comment: @Steven The downside I could see while writing this is that if someone has 2 tabs open in the same browser and is processing 2 files at the same time the session ID would be the same between both tabs and each time the progress table is updated it would be updating the same row between 2 files if it were using the session ID as a key. The other problem I can see with this, although maybe not such a major problem, is that if there were a problem with the upload then there is no guarantee that the progress row will be deleted from the database.

Comment: @Steven Continued: These problems though can be solved by using a unique ID per file. There s also the matter of the number of database calls being made on very large files. Of course this could put some strain on the server if there were high traffic, but then again this is expected which is why I suggested updating the table every certain number of rows, so perhaps this isn't really much of a problem.

Comment: @Steven Continued: Other than those problems I can't see any real downside if you just use a unique ID for each file instead of session ID. But if somebody else sees this and notices a problem hopefully they will let you know. On the upside a side effect of this method could help you keep track of the number of file processing errors by showing you incomplete records in the database.

Comment: Sour Lemon, thanks for comprehensive feedback. We are already storing a row for each uploaded file and return unique ID. This row also have a column for progress, file location etc. My external developer has chosen to use `CRON` - which I'm not sure is the best way to attack this issue - so I'm looking in to this. Unless he can convince me, your suggestions is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I use the jQuery UI suite. There is a good progessbar component: http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/#animated

EDIT:
other questions and examples: [Jquery UI Progress Bar with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802578/jquery-ui-progress-bar-with-php) and http://www.phphelp.com/forum/index.php?topic=9921.0